# how to turn off reload of page after sending ajax to php and how to fix this code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to turn off reload of page after sending AJAX to PHP? The page reloads every time when I press submit. Is it possible to send some picture without form?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e){
        $("#uploadForm").on('submit', (function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/class/pdo/add_new_field.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#targetLayer").html(data);
                },
                error: function(){}             
            });
        }));

        $('#uploadForm').submit(function () {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="uploadForm" method="POST">
    <div style="margin-left: 75px;">
        <div class="save_divs">picture<input type="file"></div>
        <div class="save_divs">name:</div>
        <div class="save_divs">date</div>
        <div class="save_divs">short_info</div>
        <div class="save_divs">long info<input type="submit"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Do i need slash (`/`) in `$.ajax` url?

Comment: You have two event handlers on the `submit` event of the form. What is `sendContactForm()`? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: remove input type submit, you can use a button that call a Javascript function (to use the ajax)

Comment: @Goikiu that's bad practice. You should always hook to the `submit` event of the form when dealing with AJAX in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. too many event handlers. Remove the second one unless `sendContactForm();` is important. If it is, update your question with it.
2. syntax error in the event handler, remove the ( from before (funtion in the submit and one of the `)` from the `}));`
3. If class is the top folder in your hierarchy you can use the /class, if it is under the form location, then no. Use "class/..."

like this

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/class/pdo/add_new_field.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#targetLayer").html(data);
            },
            error: function(){}             
        });
    }); // also a ) too many here
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, First problem is : -

1. You have submit binded twice once with `on`, once with `submit()`, use only one.
2. Now the error is coming due to the second binding,
   There is some error in sendContactForm(), due to which it never gets to the line `return false` and default page is submitted and is reloaded, check for console errors, also, to prevent confusion in future, you could probably use `e.preventDefault();` at the start of the function to stop further propogation. (thanks @rory)

   ```
   $('#uploadForm').submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       sendContactForm();
       return false;
   });
   ```

Comment: Note that the code in the second function is fine - `return false` will have the same effect as `preventDefault()` (and it will also `stopPropagation()` although that's moot in this situation). I would imagine there is an error in the `sendContactForm()` which is causing a problem.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, due to the error in sendContactForm() it is never going to the line return False, therefore page is reloading.